# Android: Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar vs Theme.Light.NoTitleBar

Tags: android, android-theme

In `res/values-v11/styles.xml`, I can't use `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` because it was added in API level 13.  Can I use `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` instead, with no visual differences?  As far as I can tell, they should both have a white background, status and navigation bars, and nothing else.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Theme.Light.NoTitleBar is slightly different.  The easiest way to resolve this and stay compatible back to Honeycomb is to create your own style that extends Theme.Holo.Light, but removes the Action Bar.  Just create a style with the following definition:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How to make compatible for API 8 ??

Comment: Srikanth, you'd need a different theme completely for API 8, as Holo wasn't introduced until API 11.

Comment: @contactmeandroid `<style name="generalNoTitleBar">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>`

Comment: @AlexAndro - Thanks.. I need help of yours for this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649023/custom-slide-to-unlock

Comment: @contactmeandroid by using Android Support Library you can use Holo Theme in APIs such as 8.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Theme.Light.NoTitleBar is based on older API level. You will get the style of Android 2.3. But Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar can give you the style of 4.0 or upper.