# Android Studio (0.4.6) hide title bar in preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

Does anyone know of a way to hide the title bar in Android Studio previews (that's the title bar on the device previews, not the title bar of Android Studio)? I am writing a full screen app and using virtually all the screen but the preview insists on showing the title bar which makes it very difficult to scale things correctly. Any ideas?

I have included my theme to show I am actually asking for the title to be hidden, JIC I have done something wrong, like I normally do ;)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/defaultButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fontSize</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance, as always.

PS: How do you do strikethrough / bold etc in code blocks? I don;t seem to be able to get it to work...

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14061826/2649012)'s the answer (which INCLUDES **.Holo.Light**).

Comment: Yep. Thanks, it was <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> that I needed to add. Can you put this as an answer please so I can give credit where credit is due?

Comment: Yes, correct. So you can take advantage of the Holo Light theming too.

Answer (score 30):

In the preview window there is a button (for me a symbol of a half filled circle, right next to the rotate screen button) that allows you to select a theme.

Go to `All > NoTitleBar.FullScreen` for a complete full-screen preview.

Comment: Thanks. I had my preview window very small and this button was hidden with no indication that exists. Make sure you're preview window is large enough!

Answer (score 15):

Just wanted to add that in order for this to work in Android Studio's preview you have to make sure the Theme selected in XML is the  same as the one selected in the little half filled circle:
[image]