# Hiding Android Action Bar in Xamarin PCL project

Tags: mono, android-actionbar, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to change the visibility of the ActionBar in all pages of an android app in a Xamarin Forms project. I used ActionBar.Hide() in the main activity but it hides it only in the front page.

```
namespace ParsellIT.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ParsellIT", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);            
            SetPage(App.GetMainPage());
            ActionBar.Hide();    
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hide it in every page but I cant access every page in the android specific code as they are built in PCL. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Theme with no Action bar in your app. For ex, you can specify Application Attribute somewere in your app:

```
[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/Icon" Theme = "@android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar")]
```

Or you can set it in AndroidManifaset.xml

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

**UPD**
Of course theme settings must be done in Android project, but it will affect on each page even in PCL.

Comment: It did not help. It still displays ActionBar

Comment: Another option is to create your own theme in Resources/values/Style.xml (create one if there is no) like there http://stackoverflow.com/a/14061826/1558147

And use it as show in answer" `Theme = "@style/MyTheme"`

Comment: adding this to my manifest actually crashes my app with a NullReferenceException on SetPage in the MainActivity

Comment: Sorry why is this marked as an answer?, the suggestion can´t be done in a ***Xamarin PCL project***.

Comment: @AhmedAlejo of course it can't. You should do it in Android project

Comment: @ad1Dima exactly my point, i was affirming not asking. The question: "**Hiding Android Action Bar in Xamarin PCL project**".
And the source code indicates usage of Xamarin.Forms.
Anyways no need to brag on this :) happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

A better option is to call:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never)
```

or

```
var page = App.GetMainPage();
Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, true)
```

or in xaml

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Mobile.Views.NewsFeedSearchView"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="{Binding IsFullScreen}"/>
```