# Is there any way to set NoActionBar theme in Application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, themes

I am making android app using Visual Studio with the Xamarin platform.
As i read the document the thing I found.

[image].

As we can see there is only three Theme we can create. So my Question is can we set `NoActionBar` theme to Application as we can set in Android Studio.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Theme with no Action bar in your app. For ex, you can specify Application Attribute in `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/Icon" Theme = "@android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar")]
```

Or set it in AndroidManifaset.xml

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

If that does not work, create a style with no action bar, like it's mentioned in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061826/85606

Comment: can we set `Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar` as we set in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

### No actionbar with styles

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">

 </style>
```